# Stored Procedure error concat()

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting error while creating stored procedure...

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CreateTableProj`(IN projName VARCHAR(200), IN tablName VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN

 SET @comnd = CONCAT('
 create table ',tablName,'(
                  select s1.name , p1.fpath , s1.version 
                  FROM test.prj1 s1 , test.prj2 p1
                  WHERE 
                        s1.id=(select id 
                                from test.prj2 p2 
                            where p2.name=',projName') 
                        and s1.id=p1.id
                  ');

 PREPARE stmt FROM @comnd;
 EXECUTE stmt;

END
```

Getting below error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
```

any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: What is the use of `DELIMITER $$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has multiple errors and bad examples of coding:

- You need `as` after the create table.
- You need double quotes around the name (unless name is numeric).
- This also fixes the `join` syntax.

Here is what I think you are trying to get:

```
create table ', tablName, ' as
     select s1.name , p1.fpath , s1.version 
     from test.prj1 s1 join
          test.prj2 p1
          on s1.id = p1.id
     where s1.id = (select id
                    from test.prj2 p2 
                    where p2.name = ''', projName'''
                   )
```

This still doesn't make sense.  The subquery insists that only one row be returned.  So this query should be the same as:

```
create table ', tablName, ' as
     select s1.name , p1.fpath , s1.version 
     from test.prj1 s1 join
          test.prj2 p1
          on s1.id = p1.id
     where p1.name = ''', projName'''
```

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER $$ is wrong snytax and it doesnt seem used anywhere in the code.Tr to remove it and run the script.